# How to use Service Fabric DNS service with dynamic ports?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I was not able to call an API from a service hosted on Service Fabric, and configured to use dynamic ports. I referred the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice) to setup the internal DNS service and named it as follows in `ApplicationManifest.xml`

```
<Service Name="Data" ServiceDnsName="services.data">
```

I tried calling the API as follows:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response1 = await client.GetAsync("https://services.data/api/v1/countries"); // throws exception
    var response2 = await client.GetAsync("https://services.data:30006/api/v1/countries"); // works
}
```

But I observe that unless the port value is explicitly provided in the Uri, it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of a DNS is translate a human readable string to an IP.

For example:

Given a domain `www.mydomain.com`, a DNS call translate it to an IP `192.168.0.1` where your request will be sent.

If you expect the client to connect on any port other than 80(http) you would have to make a request for `www.mydomain.com:81` that would be translated to`192.168.0.1:81`

On service fabric DNS the same logic applies.

Given the service: `service1` on `application1`.
The DNS entry will be: `service1.application1`
An IP resolution will redirect to: `The node IP`

If your service doesn't listen the requests on port 80, the client has to provide the port where your service is listening to.

If you plan to use dynamic assigned ports, I would recommend you using the [reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#microservices-communication-model) or using [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting)

Comment: Can you help me with configuring the service fabric such that it can access websites. I have posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/59799953/1779091